# Cómo asignar vendedores a los clientes que se van registrando desde un FORM?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Tengo un formulario donde se van registrando los clientes. Estos van llegando al sistema y se están asignando a los asesores manualmente. Lo que quiero es asignarlos automaticamente de forma equitativa. La idea es por medio de un arreglo, cargar los asesores que están almacenados en una tabla, y crear un ciclo que se vaya repitiendo cada vez que llegue al ultimo asesor.

En esta parte del código se registran los clientes y se almacenan en una tabla contactos. Lo que he intentado es lo que se encuentra en el comentario. Estoy cargando los asesores en un array para guardarlos automáticamente cada vez que se registra un cliente, pero el problema es que siempre guarda el primer asesor. No he podido recorrerlo en orden y crear un bucle.

```
if ($conexion->connect_errno) {

    echo "Error al conectar la base de datos {$conexion->connect_errno}";
}
$fecha_registro=date("Y-m-d");  
$nombre_con=isset($_POST['nombre_con'])? $_POST['nombre_con'] : NULL;

$telefono=isset($_POST['telefono'])? $_POST['telefono'] : NULL;;

$correo=isset($_POST['correo'])? $_POST['correo'] : NULL;;

$mensaje=isset($_POST['mensaje'])? $_POST['mensaje'] : NULL;

$fecha_con=$fecha_registro;

  /* $sql= "SELECT * FROM administrador where nive_usua=2 order by nombre ASC";
    $usuario=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($usuario)) { 

       $id_usuario=$row['nombre'];

    } */

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    // $query="INSERT INTO contactos  VALUES('$nombre','$telefono','$correo','$mensaje')";

    $query="INSERT INTO contactos (nombre_con, telefono, correo, mensaje,fecha_con,id_usuario) VALUES ('".$nombre_con."','".$telefono."', '".$correo."', '".$mensaje."', '".$fecha_con."' , '".$id_usuario."')" or die(mysql_error());

Los asesores, se encuentran en una tabla llamada administrador y los asigno manualmente de la siguiente manera, en un formulario donde modifico la tabla contactos y le asigno asesor a cada cliente:

    <legend>Selecione Asesor:</legend>
      <div class="form-group">

      <select name="id_usuario" class="form-control selectpicker"   id="id_usuario" data-live-search="true" title="Porfavor serleccione un usuario...">
       <?php 

            $sql= "SELECT * FROM administrador where nive_usua=2";
            $usuario=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
         ?>
            <?php while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($usuario)) { ?>

               <option value="<?php echo $row['nombre'] ?>">
               <?php echo $row['nombre']; ?>
               </option>"

          <?php  }  ?>
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: cual es el código con el que agregas asesores manualmente? cual es con el que ingresas nuevos clientes?
Que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: @JorgeArturoJuarez buen dia,  ahí edite el post de nuevo con la información que me solicitaste ,  gracias antemano

Comment: funciona pero cuando se agrega un nuevo vendedor todos todos se le asignan a este hasta que iguale los clientes de los demas

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que todos tengan el mismo numero de clientes, intenta obtener solo tu asesor que  tiene menos clientes,  tu query quedaría algo asi.

```
SELECT id_usuario FROM contactos GROUP BY id_usuario ORDER BY count(*) as num_clients ASC LIMIT 1
```